# This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled

Tags: python, debugging, anaconda, spyder, filenames

I get this message every time I start any program:

This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
Python 3.11.4 packaged by Anaconda

Spyder help shows this info:
Spyder IDE 5.4.3 (conda)
Python 3.11.4 64-bit | Qt 5.15.2 | PyQt5 5.15.7 | Windows 10

I tried to install the spider separately, downloaded the latest python version and pointed the new path to it.

Comment: Problem solved. I installed python (same version) separately from Anaconda and specified the path to it.